# Two Queries on Same Table Columns?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a query that will take specific criteria and split it into new columns on the table. For example, below I have the raw data when I do this query:

```
select Warehouse
, StockCode
, QtyOnHand
, QtyAllocated
, SalesQty1
, SalesQty2
, SalesQty3
from InvWarehouse
```

| Warehouse | StockCode | QtyOnHand | QtyAllocated | SalesQty1 | SalesQty2 | SalesQty3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OF | ACN2-1015-2.3 | 36900.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 01 | ACN2-1015-2.3 | 22475.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| OF | ACN2-8125-1.9 | 108000.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 01 | ACN2-8125-1.9 | 45600.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| OF | CA-2520S-151ZY | 74632.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |

Some of these parts are in both OF and 01 Warehouses and what I want to do is compare the OF QtyOnHands to the 01 QtyOnHands.

I built this query, but the qtyonhands seem to be wrong so I must be doing something incorrectly. How do I correct this?

```
select
          WOF.Warehouse
        , WOF.StockCode
        , WOF.QtyOnHand
        , W01.QtyOnHand
        , W01.QtyAllocated
        , W01.[SalesQty1]
        , W01.[SalesQty2]
        , W01.[SalesQty3]
    from InvWarehouse W01
    left join InvWarehouse WOF on WOF.Warehouse = W01.Warehouse
    where W01.QtyOnHand > '0'
    and WOF.Warehouse = 'OF'
```

As said before, I'm trying to split the data to get two columns for Quantity On Hand. One for OF and one for 01. But I ONLY want to show OF in the warehouse column. So something like the below:

| Warehouse | StockCode | W01.QtyOnHand | WOF.QtyOnHand | W01.QtyAllocated | WOF.SalesQty1 | WOF.SalesQty2 | WOF.SalesQty3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OF | ACN2-1015-2.3 | 36900.000000 | 36900.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| OF | ACN2-8125-1.9 | 108000.000000 | 36900.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |

Let me know if further clarification is needed, but bottom line is I want to pull the data from Warehouse = 01 and also Warehouse = OF and be able to add the QtyOnHand 01 onto my table that has QtyOnHand OF. So basically two queries where one shows Warehouse 01 and the other shows Warehouse OF, combined into one query that I can grab specific info from.

Comment: You say "qtyonhands seem to be wrong", but that query wouldn't produce wrong qtyonhands values.  It would produce an error message.  I don't see a reference to W01 in the FROM clause.  Please post the actual query that is returning wrong data.

Comment: I don't see StockCode ACN2-12175-2.3 in your input.  How would it get into the desired output?  WOF.QtyOnHand in the output is 36900 for every StockCode.  How would the query know to do that?  Please do a better job of aligning the expected results with the input data.

Comment: @dougp I corrected it for the query that I used. My apologies.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  How would you know that OF - ACN2-8125-1.9 would return 36900 in column 4 of your output?  That query returns data only for warehouse WOF.  it will never return data for warehouse W01.  Since you are joining the table to itself on only Warehouse, the number of rows you'll get is (COUNT(DISTINCT StockCode)) squared.  So, for the input you provided, that would be 9 rows.  Maybe go through a basic SQL tutorial before asking SQL questions.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not match your expected output exactly. As the comments suggest, I don't think you've described your problem clearly (I don't understand why you would have W01.QtyOnHand as 36900).

However, I *suspect* you are looking for something like:

```
select
      WOF.Warehouse
    , W01.StockCode
    , WOF.QtyOnHand
    , W01.QtyOnHand
    , W01.QtyAllocated
    , W01.[SalesQty1]
    , W01.[SalesQty2]
    , W01.[SalesQty3]
from InvWarehouse W01
left join InvWarehouse WOF on WOF.StockCode = W01.StockCode
where W01.QtyOnHand > 0
and WOF.Warehouse = 'OF'
and W01.Warehouse = '01'
```

Note the join here is `ON WOF.StockCode = W01.StockCode` (not `ON WOF.Warehouse = W01.Warehouse`) and I've added a new condition `and W01.Warehouse = '01'`. All together, this will give you two rows as you expect and the `WOF.*` columns in your `SELECT` will refer to the warehouse='OF' row for each `StockCode` and the `W01.*` columns in your `SELECT` will refer to the warehouse='01' row for each `StockCode`.

Comment: I would like to personally thank you because this is exactly what I'm looking for and where my confusion was. I appreciate you deciphering it to give the solution I'm looking for. Thank you.